# Signal handler, python

Tags: python, multithreading, sigint

I have a multithreaded program and use the signal.signal(SIGINT,func) to kill all threads when ctrl c is pressed. The question I have is this:

I have to call signal.signal(...) from main in python. Do I have to call that on a loop or can I just set it once and whenever the user presses ctrl c, the signal will be caught?

Answer (score 2):

Only the main tread can handle signals.  Just make all your threads "daemonic" ones (set the thread object's `.daemon` property to `True` before you start the thread) to ensure the threads terminate when the main thread does.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but in main, do I need to call signa.signal(SIGINT, func) in a loop (e.g. While true) or can I just call it once in main?

Comment: @Juli, just once, as long as `main` terminates as a result of executing `func`.

Comment: you say that `.daemon == True` threads will be interrupted and killed when the main thread terminates?